# Using bin counts as weights for random number selection

Tags: matlab

I have a set of data that I wish to approximate via random sampling in a non-parametric manner, e.g.:

```
eventl=
4
5
6
8
10
11
12
24
32
```

In order to accomplish this, I initially bin the data up to a certain value:

```
binsize = 5;
nbins = 20;
[bincounts,ind] = histc(eventl,1:binsize:binsize*nbins);
```

Then populate a matrix with all possible numbers covered by the bins which the approximation can choose:

```
sizes = transpose(1:binsize*nbins);
```

To use the bin counts as weights for selection i.e. bincount (1-5) = 2, thus the weight for choosing 1,2,3,4 or 5 = 2 whilst (16-20) = 0 so 16,17,18, 19 or 20 can never be chosen, I simply take the bincounts and replicate them across the bin size:

```
w = repelem(bincounts,binsize);
```

To then perform weighted number selection, I use:

```
[~,R] = histc(rand(1,1),cumsum([0;w(:)./sum(w)]));
R = sizes(R);
```

For some reason this approach is unable to approximate the data. It was my understanding that was sufficient sampling depth, the binned version of `R` would be identical to the binned version of `eventl` however there is significant variation and often data found in bins whose weights were 0.

Could anybody suggest a better method to do this or point out the error?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding your explanation of how you choose the weights: say your data is [5 5 6 6 6 7 8]. Now you make a bin #1 containing [5 6] and a bin #2 containing [7 8]. Do you want as output 1's and 2's, with 2.5 times as many 1's as 2's? Do you want 5,6,7,8 with weights [2,3,1,1], respectively?

Comment: If the data was [5 5 6 6 6 7 8] in bins of 1-5 (count = 2) and 6-10 (count = 5), the selection of 1,2,3,4 or 5 occurs at a frequency 2.5x lower than the choice of 6,7,8,9 or 10. The bin count describes the frequency at which any number in that bin-range can be chosen.

Comment: That would mean that a 6 should get chosen with equal frequency as 8, right, even though the raw data contais 3x as many 6's?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The same goes for 9 - even though it does not appear in the raw data at all, it will be chosen with equal frequency to 6 or 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a better method, I suggest `randsample`:

```
 values = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]; %# values from which you want to pick
 numberOfElements = 1000; %# how many values you want to pick 
 weights = [2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1]; %# weights given to the values (1-5 are twice as likely as 6-8)

 sample = randsample(values, numberOfElements, true, weights);
```

Note that even with 1000 samples, the distribution does not exactly correspond to the weights, so if you only pick 20 samples, the histogram may look rather different.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My main issue is in the generation of the weights and alignment of these with the bins correctly rather than variation in frequency. My approach somehow generates values in bins whose values should be 0 and thus never selected.

Comment: This method seems to work well and produce a near-identical result. Not sure why my original method does not!